# Detect if a textbox does not contain certain words

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to know how to detect if a textbox does not contain certain words. For example if the textbox did not contain 'who', 'what', 'why', 'when' or 'where' some sort of function would run.

JavaScript:

```
function command() {
    var srchVar = document.getElementById("srch");
    var srch = srchVar.value;
    var t = srch;
    if (srch == '') {
        alert('Please do not leave the field empty!');
    }
    else if (srch.indexOf('time') != -1) {
        alert('The current time according to your computer is' + ShowTime(new Date()));
    }
    else if (srch.indexOf('old are you') != -1) {
        alert("I am as old as you want me to be.");
    }
    else {
        if (confirm('I am sorry but I do not understand that command. Would you like to search Google for that command?') == true) {
            window.open('https://google.co.uk/#q=' + srch, '_blank');
        }
        else { /* Nothing */ }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <input class="search-field" id="srch" onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event);" placeholder="ask me anything" spellcheck="false">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to better explain what is happening, what isn't happening and what you would like to happen. As it is your question is unclear, and as such it is off-topic for Stack Overflow until it can be edited to fit within the guidelines.

Comment: Have you tried writing any HTML that calls this javascript code?

Comment: What is your question ??

Comment: you have already the conditions in your code, what is the problem and what you want to acheive ?

Comment: @omar_latreche, it would help if you included a [**minimal**, working, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, show the behavior of just one or two of your conditions, and then describe your desired behavior and how they differ. Also, I'm not a javascript programmer, but perhaps there's a data structure in which you can store your question/answer pairs, and over which you can then conditionally iterate?

Comment: Your edits did not address my previous comment. What is happening? What isn't happening? What would you like to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to call that function when you press a button.
Try something in your HTML like:

```
<input class="info" onclick="contains();" type="button">
```

And in your JS

```
function contains() {
    var srchVar = document.getElementById("srch");
    var srch = srchVar.value;

    if (
        (srch.indexOf('who')==-1) &&
        (srch.indexOf('what')==-1) &&
        (srch.indexOf('why')==-1) &&
        (srch.indexOf('when')==-1) &&
        (srch.indexOf('where')==-1)
    ) {
          alert("That is not a question");
    }
}
```

You will want to merge this with your `command()` function in the future.

Also, what does `info();` do ?